# sequelize (js) association for multiple columns with one table

Tags: sql, node.js, sequelize.js

hope you're doing great.

I have an issue with sequelizejs I cannot get to work for some reason, no matter how I set up the associations in between tables. My problem is, I have a table, called **Results**, this table has a structure of:

```
| id (primary) | first_guy_id | second_guy_id | third_guy_id | notes |
|--------------|--------------|---------------|--------------|-------|
|              |              |               |              |       |
```

This table connects to **Users**, and here comes the fun part, the table **Users** has a simple structure, like so

```
| id (primary) | first | last |
|--------------|-------|------|
|              |       |      |
```

What I would like to do with sequelize is, to get a result (in json afterwards) that looks similar to this, nested with connections:

```
{
  "id": 17,
  "first_guy_id": { "id": 12, "first": "First .... },
  "second_guy_id": { "id": 14, "first": "First .... },
  "third_guy_id": { "id": 19, "first": "First .... },
  "notes": "notes",
}
```

Doing the SQL JOIN in regular SQL is easy even if all the id's for each column (first_guy, second ...) are different but reach such a goal in sequelize rendered myself completely hopeless.

When I associate the two tables this way:

```
Results.hasOne(User, { as:'first_guy', foreignKey: 'first_guy' });
User.belongsTo(Results, { as: 'first_guy' });
```

When doing the actual call using

```
findOne ...
   include: [
        { model: User,
          include: [
            {
              model: User,
              as: 'first_ugy',
              where: {
                    'id': sequelize.col('Results.first_guy_id')
              },
            }
          ],
        },
```

I get an error of:

```
ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'Results.user_id' in 'field list'
```

This is of course because it looks for user_id as foreign key, connecting to table "User" it thinks the key should be user_id.

Two problems I have finding this solution are:

1. How do I join the result on any field with sequelize same way I would do with regular SQL (pseudo code here) "**INNER JOIN User.id on Results.first_guy_id as MY_FIELD_NAME**"
2. How do I join all of those fields to the same model but with different results for each column? So the get result from **Results** would return nested 3 different users by their ID listed in the **Results** table in that specific row. Using same model?

I went through the docs of sequelize, tried many combinations but never achieving the result. It almost feels like i would have to end up writing models, that are named like those fields "First_gu", "second_guy", "third_guy" for Sequalize to work and auto append the "_id" there like it does with the **User** model now. But it feels like too much of an effort for something that should be solved by the "foreignKey" attribute in the belongsTo / hasOne?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's a simple solution. You should define relation for every result's column.

```
Results.belongsTo(User, { as:'firstGuy', foreignKey: 'first_guy_id'});
Results.belongsTo(User, { as:'secondGuy', foreignKey: 'second_guy_id'});
...
```

Then you can do querying like this:

```
Results.findById(resultId, {
   include: [{
      model: User,
      as: 'firstGuy'
   }, {
      model: User,
      as: 'secondGuy'
   },
   ...
   ]
}).then(function(result){
   var firstGuyUser = result.firstGuy;
});
```